# Login to Java site with WWW::Scripter charset issue

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, www-authenticate

I'm trying to login to a java website using WWW::Scripter module.  Using the WWW::Mechanize module works fine, but once authenticated the site has JavaScript functions that I need to call - hence needing Scripter.

After doing a large amount of troubleshooting I have found that the difference in packets sent from the click() event are  the Content-Type varaibale.
Mechanize has:
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n 
but Scripter has: 
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset="ISO-8859-1"\r\n
(This is viewed using WireShark)

This explains the error I am receiving from the website which is:

> error message: "ISO-8859-1" error stack trace:
>   java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: "ISO-8859-1"
>           at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Charset.java:305)
>           at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:439)
>           at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
>
> ```
>     at java.lang.StringCoding$DecoderCache.makeDecoder(StringCoding.java(Com
> ```
>
> piled Code))
>           at java.lang.StringCoding$1.run(StringCoding.java(Compiled Code))
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged1(Native Method)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java(Com
>   piled Code))
>           at java.lang.StringCoding$DecoderCache.getDecoder(StringCoding.java(Comp
>   iled Code))
>           at java.lang.StringCoding.getDecoder(StringCoding.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
>           at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java(Compiled Code))
>           at java.lang.String.(String.java(Compiled Code))
>           at java.lang.String.(String.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.RequestUtils.parsePostData(RequestUti
>   ls.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters(SRTServ
>   letRequest.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getParameterNames(SRTSe
>   rvletRequest.java(Compiled Code))
>           at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameterNames(ServletRequestW
>   rapper.java(Compiled Code))
>           at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java(Compil
>   ed Code))
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProc
>   essor.java(Compiled Code))
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.ja
>   va(Compiled Code))
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inl
>   ined Compiled Code))
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Comp
>   iled Code))
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code
>   ))
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code
>   ))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StrictServletInstance.doService(Stric
>   tServletInstance.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StrictLifecycleServlet._service(Stric
>   tLifecycleServlet.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.IdleServletState.service(StrictLifecy
>   cleServlet.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StrictLifecycleServlet.service(Strict
>   LifecycleServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.service(ServletInstan
>   ce.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ValidServletReferenceState.dispatch(V
>   alidServletReferenceState.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstanceReference.dispatch(Ser
>   vletInstanceReference.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilte
>   rChain.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.infostream.web.filters.HibernateSessionFilter.doFilter(HibernateS
>   essionFilter.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterI
>   nstanceWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilte
>   rChain.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.infostream.web.filters.IdentificationFilter.doFilter(Identificati
>   onFilter.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterI
>   nstanceWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilte
>   rChain.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.handleWebAppDi
>   spatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAp
>   pRequestDispatcher.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebApp
>   RequestDispatcher.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WebAppInvoker.doForward(WebAppInvoker.jav
>   a(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WebAppInvoker.handleInvocationHook(WebApp
>   Invoker.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.cache.invocation.CachedInvocation.handleInvoc
>   ation(CachedInvocation.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.cache.invocation.CacheableInvocationContext.i
>   nvoke(CacheableInvocationContext.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srp.ServletRequestProcessor.dispatchByURI(Ser
>   vletRequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.oselistener.OSEListenerDispatcher.service(OSE
>   Listener.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnect
>   ion.java(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.ja
>   va(Compiled Code))
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java(Compiled Code)
>   )
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))

The code I'm using to test the login is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use WWW::Scripter;

my $urlLogin = "XXX";

my $viper = WWW::Scripter->new();

$viper->use_plugin('JavaScript');

$viper->get($urlLogin);

$viper->form_name('loginForm');

$viper->field(username => "xxx");
$viper->field(password => "xxx");

$viper->click();
```

As mentioned before this works fine if I use WWW::Mechanize instead of WWW::Scripter.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to remove the charset field in the Content-Type of the packet being POST'ed.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you cross posted this question to PerlMonks and they answered your question.

On CPAN in the module comments I see this: "BUGS: There are too many to list! This thing is currently very unstable, to put it mildly."

I think the best javascript capable web automation is WWW::Mechanize::Firefox. To use this you have to install a Firefox on your machine and add an addon. The the perl script will use firefox to render the page with javascript through this addon. It the page works with Firefox to could mess with it.

Regards,